# Is there any way to auto generate objects from a class?

Tags: java, android

I have a class with 5 variables, and 3 out of the 5 will be the same for every new object. Is there a way to create, say, 100 objects, from a string file containing 100 items?

Comment: so if you want same variable values, why dont you initialize it ?

Comment: I think what you are asking is possible, but I'd need more details. Are you simply wanting to create 1 new object instance for every item in a file? I assume you'll want to initialize each object with some data from the file, correct? I might be assuming too much?

Comment: Your questions is rather vague, but if I understand what you're saying correctly, you should be able to use a superclass to store the 3 variables that you say will be the same. No need to store them 100 separate times.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: *there a way to create, say, 100 objects, from a string file containing 100 items*? specificaly what did you meant by *item*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah of course can you do that. I wont write code for you, but the following steps should help to come to a solution yourself.

- Make a constructor delegation, one which accepts 5 values. And another which accepts just the 2 which are not changing. This constructor then overloads the other with the default values. `this(3,2,"a", input1, input2)`
- Initialize the 3 variables which are not changing directly in the field declaration: `private int initialSetVariable1 = 3;`

Comment: So after each object is constructed how can i refer to each on specifically?

Comment: @Keith what do you mean with `refer`? You create an object like `MyObject object = new MyObject()` and this then 100 times in your case, if I understood your question correctly

Comment: I mean if I were to create a listview would I have to write out 100 elif statements or is there some way to get the identity of the particular item selected in the listview using the same system?

Comment: @Keith you could store the 100 objects in a `List` and then you could scan the list for the item that was selected